# How to create ordered list with different circle ring colors

Tags: html, css

I am using an ordered list  display results. Now I would like to add a circle to the number with colors changing from green to red. The use being the first result is the priority and the others to follow are less. So the color gradient changes from green to red.

```css
.listAddress li {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: list-item;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #252424;
    font-size: 12px;
     width: auto;
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
```

```html
<ol class="listAddress">
<li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
<li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
<li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't think that will be implemented using pure CSS. It should need JavaScript.

Comment: How many results do you expect? Is there an upper limit to how many you display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this helps.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6caq9mh0/)**

```css
body { background: white; }
.listAddress {
  padding-left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.listAddress:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, red);
}
.listAddress li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.listAddress li:before {
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="listAddress">
  <li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
  <li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
  <li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
  <li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
  <li>365 W Northwest Hwy, Palatine, IL 60067, USA</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an complete answer but you can use :nth-child selector it is supported by latest browsers.

```
li:nth-child(1) { color: #636393; }
li:nth-child(2) { color: #B5222D; }
li:nth-child(3) { color: #D4953C; }
li:nth-child(4) { color: #609491; }
li:nth-child(5) { color: #87A248; }
```

Or for full browser support you can do this

```
li { color: #636393; }
li+li { color: #B5222D; }
li+li+li { color: #D4953C; }
li+li+li+li { color: #609491; }
li+li+li+li+li { color: #87A248; }
```

But can't apply gradient for li element programmatically with pure css. There are javascript examples about it.